# Ionic Customized Tabs Deactivated and Activated

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to setup an Ionic app with tabs at the bottom which basically have two states. Activated and Deactivated. I've easily managed to create the tabs bar and now I want to do the same as in these pictures, but I don't if there is any other way besides pure CSS.

Deactivated (With the arrow in the middle, and when clicked, it becomes activated)[image]

Activated[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one way to do this that is through css. U have to change the ionic default css file where tab activated and deactivated css resides just customize that css as u required.